# "Remind about" vs "Remind of"

Tags: prepositions, phrase-meaning, difference

I would like to know which phrasal verb is the correct one to be used when talking about *an appointment*.

I have heard some say **remind about** is the correct one because it talks about something in the future that I have to do. And I have heard others say **remind of** is the correct one because it's the one to be used for something already set such as an appointment.

So, what do you think? Which one should I use in this case?

Here are a few example sentences:

> 1. The alarm **reminded** Tim **of** his appointment.
> 2. The alarm **reminded** Tim **about** his appointment.
> 3. Thank you for **reminding** me **of** my doctor's appointment tomorrow—I had completely forgotten!
> 4. Thank you for **reminding** me **about** my doctor's appointment tomorrow—I had completely forgotten!

Comment: One might use *remind about* more broadly: “reminding me about Chicago” means reminding me about *something* relating to Chicago, which could be an upcoming event there *or* that Chicago is an exception to something I just said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are correct, and you have correctly described the distinction. I personally use both. I would not call one more correct than the other. I'm not aware of any regional differences with regard to preferring one form over the other.

Answer (score -1):

Both are right.
Preferably, remind of is used for occasions
Remind about, is used for items

Comment: Welcome to English Language Learners! While this may be correct, we like our answers to be backed up by references. You can [edit] your answer to include one (e.g. an online dictionary). See the Help Center article [answer].